# BASH Prepend timestamp to stdout and stderr

Tags: bash, process, timestamp, stdout, stderr

I am trying to prepend a timestamp to all lines in stdout and stderr. However I do not want to redirect either of them to a file. This command is being run in a script by a process manager (pm2) which will then log stdout and stderr to their respective file. I am trying to modify the stream (without combining them) and insert the timestamp before is logged by pm2. I can get either of them working in isolation but run into issues modifying both. I appreciate any assistance you can provide.

Here is my somewhat working code

```
python3.6 ./bot.py > >(gawk '{ print strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]"), $0 }') 2> >(gawk '{ print strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]"), $0 }')
```

Comment: Sorry that was confusing language, I mean before it's logged by pm2. pm2 is the thing running the script. I will update to make this more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redirect output from the second `gawk` command back to stderr:

```
python3.6 ./bot.py \
    > >(gawk '{ print strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]"), $0 }') \
   2> >(gawk '{ print strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]"), $0 }' >&2)
#                                             this part here ^^^
```

Without that, the second `gawk` command is taking input from `python3.6`'s stderr, but sending output to the same stdout as everything else.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for. There was one final piece I needed to complete the puzzle. That piece was fflush()
the final code looks like this:  
`python3.6 ./bot.py
    > >(gawk '{ print strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]"), $0 } fflush()')
   2> >(gawk '{ print strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]"), $0 } fflush()' >&2)
`